# How can this loopy array process be vectorized or otherwise sped up?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider two arrays, p and q.

p , in this small sample, has rows with indices 0 to 4, so p's rows hold some permutation of the nine digits -4 to 4.

q always has 3 columns, but usually has a very large number of rows.  In each row of q:
 q[0] gives the index of a **row in p**
 q[1] gives the value of an element in that row of p
 q[2] temporarily holds a placeholder 0 that we are about to change.

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array([[3, -2, 4, 0, 1, -1, 2, -3, -4],
              [0, 4, -4, 3, -2, 1, -3, -1, 2],
              [-4, -3, -1, 2, 4, 0, 1, -2, 3],
              [0, -3, 4, 3, -2, -1, 1, 2, -4],
              [-2, 2, -4, 4, 0, 1, 2, -1, -2]])


q = np.array([[3,  2, 0],
              [1,  3, 0],
              [0,  2, 0],
              [2, -1, 0],
              [1,  1, 0],
              [4,  0, 0],
              [3, -4, 0]])
```

PROBLEM: **for each row in q**, I want to assign a replacement value to q[2] as follows:.

consider the q row `[3,  2, 0]`:
 I take row p[3], then determine the column holding element 2. (this has index = 7)
 So, I assign 7 to the last element in the q row, giving `[3, 2, 7]`.

In a similar way, the q row `[1,  3, 0]` becomes `[1,  3, 3]`.

The final output would be:

```
         q = [[3,  2, 7]
              [1,  3, 3]
              [0,  2, 6]
              [2, -1, 2]
              [1,  1, 5]
              [4,  0, 4]
              [3, -4, 8]]
```

I currently loop through each row of q, looping, in turn through each column of p to 'find' the target element for that row.
I'm hoping there's a way to vectorize or otherwise speed up this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it without loops:

```
q[:,2] = np.where(p[q[:,0]]==q[:,1][:,None])[1]
```

`p[q[:,0]]` selects the rows, `p[q[:,0]]==q[:,1][:,None]` finds the matching element in selected rows to second column of `q`, and `np.where` finds the location of matching elements to assign to third column of `q`.

output:

```
[[ 3  2  7]
 [ 1  3  3]
 [ 0  2  6]
 [ 2 -1  2]
 [ 1  1  5]
 [ 4  0  4]
 [ 3 -4  8]]
```